# Total no. of solutions of $dy/dx + |y| =0 , \ y (0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find total number solutions  of $dy/dx + |y| =0 , \ y (0)=0$ , should I form two diferential equations by considering y positive and negative , i don't seem to be confident. Hints for this? Thanks

Comment: has a unique solution $y(x)$ that is identically zero.

Comment: yes, considering $y$ positive and $y$ negative separately seems like a great idea

Comment: I think abel is right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The differential equation
$$y'=-|y|$$
satisfies the assumptions of the existence and uniqueness theorem at $(0,0)$: The right side $f(x,y):=|y|$ is obviously continuous in $x$ and $y$; furthermore one has
$$\bigl|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)\bigr| =\bigl||y_1|-||y_2|\bigr|\leq |y_1-y_2|\ ,$$
whence $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with respect to the second variable. It follows that the IVP
$$y'=-|y|,\qquad y(0)=0$$
has a **unique solution**. Since you can easily guess this solution you are done.

Comment: As alex stated out earlier y=0 , the identical solution

Comment: Sir what is wrong with other answer

Comment: There is no other answer answering your question.

Comment: Answer byAhaanS.Rungta

Comment: ...is an "answer" which does not answer the question. :-)